# GCM FATAL EXCEPTION error

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

My android applications throws a error, Have searched online still don't understand what the error is!, any help appreciated..

```
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-3]
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at com.Test.Messaging.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:43)
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
 03-14 15:46:02.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My GCMIntentService class where it throws the exception :

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {                      
    Log.i(TAG, "Recieved");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");                         
    String oo[] = message.split("-");                                           

    String kk = "R";
    String msg = oo[3];
    String che = oo[2];
    see = oo[1];

    if (kk.equals(oo[0])) {                 

        RandomMsg.test = msg;
        RandomMsg.pool= see;
    } else {


    display(context, message);                  
}
}
```

Comment: Post class GCMIntentService

Comment: Done..Please have a look

Comment: Let's try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is generated because `oo[]` array contains only 2 value. You have to check array lengh before you call oo[index]. You can update your method as is shown below:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {                      
    Log.i(TAG, "Recieved");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");                         
    String oo[] = message.split("-");                                           
    int length = oo.length;
    String kk = "R";
    String msg = length > 3 ? oo[3] : "";
    String che = length > 2 ? oo[2] : "";
    see = length >1 oo[1] : "";

    if (kk.equals(oo[0])) {                 

        RandomMsg.test = msg;
        RandomMsg.pool= see;
    } else {


    display(context, message);                  
}
}
```

The issue will disappeared but the problem can be biggest as you think. I suppose that you should check the `message` value on debug and make sure that it is this value which you want to get.

Comment: oo[] contains 6 values, why is it necessary to check array value?, what does ::   String msg = length > 3 ? oo[3] : ""; do? Thanks for your reply

Comment: oo[] doean't contains 6 values. There is scenario that oo conatins only 2 values. This is its what your log says. Log oo length and message value and make sure that it really contains 6 value as you think

Comment: I tried your solution, still get same error except this changed.. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  length=2; index=2

Comment: same error on logcat. only change:  ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 ...

Comment: It can be the same error. Do you  copy full of my code? Do you check length everywhere? For che value too?

Comment: And did you try my solution?

Comment: Just tried again.. It did work thanks!.. Can you just briefly tell me why it throwed that error? and what this does ... length > 3 ? oo[3] : "";  ?? please

Comment: Previous you just try to get item with index 3, if oo table doesn't contain it you had exception. Now you call msg = length > 3 ? oo[3] : ""; this means that if table has length greatest than 3 you can get item with index 3 if not you set empty sting

Comment: what excatly does ? do?, If you can explain it again.. still slightly confused at what that line does :(.. and yes I will accept it :)

Comment: this is simply form of `Sting msg; if(length > 3){ msg = oo[3];} else {msg = "";}`

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak hello konrad you online? :)

Comment: Yes? Do you have any problem?